# How do I capture the URL after an external website login in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, url, browser

I want to retrieve the URL after opening an external website pop up in my ReactJS/NodeJS application. Basically in my application, I have a button that redirects the page to microsoft online login page. What I want is the URL of the page after the user logs into microsoft online.

Is there any way that's possible? If so, what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to another webpage, your React application is no longer being served to your browser, and can't do anything. You would need to have a script running on the microsoft website, either by writing it in the source code (which I doubt you can do) or by some other method such as a browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to track different systems like methods @izb mentioned, if they already dont provide. 
Many systems provides information from their servers, push/ping systems. 
One of the payment systems, I redirect  request, customer pays, and they redirects the page I entered before in their panel, like successful or fail pages.